# How can I recover from a Sway crash?

Tags: arch-linux, debugging, crash, sway

I crash pretty frequently when using Sway. The biggest culprit is OpenOffice, but sometimes Chrome crashes. These crashes are always freezes; so the screen just freezes. I know it is a low level crash (not an application crash) because the mouse pointer freezes too. If just the application crashes it is not a problem because the mouse still moves and I can usually input MOD+Shift+Q which will close the offending application, or worst case scenario I just open a terminal and kill the application.

However, when Sway itself crashes then the mouse pointer freezes and I know I am screwed because I lose all control over the keyboard.

I know it is just Sway and Arch is fine because if press the reset button on the computer, then I get a clean shutdown, so Arch is still there humming along. It is Sway and its hardware acceleration that are borked.

So, the question is how can I deal with this? (Other than by turning the computer on and off, which is what I am doing.) Is there a way to get the keyboard back so I can get to an Arch console and terminate the Sway session? On a related note, when I start Sway I can no longer open system consoles (Alt-F2 etc) because apparently Sway is seizing the keyboard and remapping the system console hotkeys somehow.

Comment: "I can no longer open system consoles (Alt-F2 etc)" is that a typo? You usually switch to a different tty with Ctrl-Alt-F2, not just Alt-F2.

Comment: @Wieland Hmm, maybe I just got the hotkey wrong.

Comment: I dont know sway, but you might be able to set up a watchdog background process that uses `swaymsg -t get_version` to see if the server is responding, and if not kill it.

Comment: "I know it is just Sway and Arch is fine because if press the reset button on the computer, then I get a clean shutdown," ? with Reset you never get a "clean shutdown". If your desktop hangs, try get a console (Alt+Fx), if that does not work, ssh to your PC from another device and powerdown from there, and if nothing works, there is still the Magic SysRq key https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key